# Most efficient way to return a nested array that includes a string (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'd like to know if there's a more efficient method of accessing a nested array based on a matched value instead of using 'forEach' or a 'for' loop.

This is what I have at the moment:

```js
var a = [
  ["aaa", "111", "!!!"],
  ["bbb", "222", "@@@"],
  ["ccc", "333", "###"],
  ["ddd", "444", "$$$"]
];

var b = "222";

var c;

a.forEach((aa) => {
 if (aa.includes(b)) c = aa;
});

// Ideally c would return ["bbb", "222", "@@@"]

console.log(c);
```

Thank you

Comment: Depends on how often `a` and its content changes, and how often you intend to perform the related task.

Comment: you can use filter, but filter itself would do a for loop  under the hood (if I am not mistaken). var c = a.filter((aa) => aa.includes(b));

Comment: Do you want do find the first array that matches your search?

Comment: @ASDFGerte The content wouldn't change very often, and the task would run whenever a user clicks on an element. One value from that element would run against the array to return related values.

Comment: In that case, you can create a data structure more suitable for searching. However, if it only occurs on a user's click, then this looks like premature optimization. Just loop, and be done with it. A typical user can't click more often than 8 times a second, so unless the data is very large, it won't create a performance issue.

Comment: @GlenK Thanks. I guess I wouldn't say for loops are out of the question and it may be just what I need in this instance. I'm only seeing what alternatives there are in this case.

Comment: If you only want to find the first match, then you should break out of the loop when you have found what you are looking for.

Comment: @some ideally, as I don't plan on any values being shared between nested arrays. and if there are then return the first one.

Comment: @ASDFGerte good point. thanks.

Comment: This is tagged ecmascript-5 and you’re using `var`, but you’re also using an arrow function. Is `Map` supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to find the first array that has your needle:

```js
var a = [
  ["aaa", "111", "!!!"],
  ["bbb", "222", "@@@"],
  ["ccc", "333", "###"],
  ["ddd", "444", "$$$"]
];



function search(haystack, needle) {
  return haystack.find( item => item.includes(needle) );
}

console.log(search(a,'222'));
```

If your data is static, you can create a cache, and use the needle to get the array.

```js
var a = [
  ["aaa", "111", "!!!"],
  ["bbb", "222", "@@@"],
  ["ccc", "333", "###"],
  ["ddd", "444", "$$$"]
];

const cache = a.reduce(
  (out, row) => {
    for (const item of row) out[item] = row;
    return out;
  },
  Object.create(null)
);


console.log(cache['222']);
```

Modern ES2019 version, using flatMap and Map:

```js
const a = [
  ["aaa", "111", "!!!"],
  ["bbb", "222", "@@@"],
  ["ccc", "333", "###"],
  ["ddd", "444", "$$$"]
];

const m = new Map(a.flatMap(r=>r.map(i=>[i,r])));

console.log(m.get('222'));
```

Comment: The OP asked for the most efficient way to do this.   This is a brute force search that is not very efficient because the data is not very well organized for this type of searching.  If, as the OP says, the data does not change very often and it regularly needs to be searched like this, then a more efficient data structure should be built, perhaps a `Map` of all the items in all the arrays with the array value as key and the array it came from as the value.  Then, a quick lookup operation in the `Map` will tell you which array it's in.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, but it is more efficient than looping through all values with forEach (that continues to go through every element, even if the value has been found.)

Comment: Why use an object for your second option (that forces string conversion for keys) instead of a `Map` that could handle all data types?

Comment: @jfriend00 Because the post asked for a string.

Comment: Is a plain object better than a `Map` in some way?  The plain object already has a problem that certain property names conflict such as "hasOwnProperty", "valueOf", "toString", etc... that using a `Map` does not.

Comment: @jfriend00 A plain object should work in any browser or javascript dialect or version. I considered using it in the first place, but decided I didn't want to make it more complicated than necessary. I also considered using a weakmap to the object in dom, but I need to see more code to see if that is a preferred way to go.

Comment: which one is the most efficient? Just simple question

Comment: @leo.fcx You have to profile that with your data with the right engine if you want to know. It depends on how the engine have implemented it. A map could be faster, since it dosen't have to search the prototype. A map is the proffered way if you can use ES6 or later, since all problems using an object is solved.

Comment: @jfriend00 Changed `{}` to `Object.create(null)`, so the object does not have any properties.